# Doctrine2 Self Reference Query -- Doesn't work

Tags: doctrine-orm

`$` I am trying to create following scenario with doctrine 2 query builder

```
SELECT 
    p . *
FROM
    _tree p
    LEFT JOIN
    _tree c ON p.id = c.parent_id
       AND (c.lft >= p.lft AND c.rgt <= p.rgt)
WHERE
    p.id = 3
```

I have set following relationship self generated by Doctrine2

```
    class Tree {

    /**
     * @var \Tree
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tree")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $parent;

      // other code
    }
```

here is my repo class

```
_em->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('p')
           ->from('Entity\Tree', 'p')
           ->leftJoin('p.Entity\Tree','c', 'ON','p.id = c.parent_id');

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

but I couldn't get it done. It throws following errors

> [Tue Oct 01 22:30:11 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:
>   Uncaught exception  'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with
>   message 'SELECT p FROM Entity\Tree p LEFT JOIN p.Entity\Tree c ON
>   p.id = c.parent_id' in 
>   /var/www/pcb_frame_work/System/Libraries/Vendors/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:39\nStack
>   trace:\n#0 
>   /var/www/pcb_frame_work/System/Libraries/Vendors/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(429):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::dqlError('SELECT p FROM
>   E...')\n#1
>   /var/www/pcb_frame_work/System/Libraries/Vendors/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(925):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->semanticalError('Class
>   Entity\Ed...')\n#2
>   /var/www/pcb_frame_work/System/Libraries/Vendors/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1561):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->JoinAssociationPathExpression()\n#3
>   /var/www/pcb_frame_work/System/Libraries/Vendors/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1506):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->JoinAssociationDeclaration()\n#4
>   /var/www/pcb_frame_work/System/Libraries/Vendors/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1435):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->Join()\n#5
>   /var/www/pcb_frame_work/System/Librari in 
>   /var/www/pcb_frame_work/System/Libraries/Vendors/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php
>   on  line 49, referer:

Comment: Can you add the complete definition of your Tree entity? Maybe that gives a clear view of the left and right columns you use in you example query

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand you completely, but I think you have to change your ManyToOne relation to:

```
/**
 * @var \Tree
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tree", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $parent;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tree", mappedBy="parent")
 */
private $children;
```

That way you can access the children of a class with `$Tree->children` and it's parent with `$Tree->parent`.

More information about self referencing associations can be found here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing